# why a specific format of argument is working on jointplot but not in lmplot

Tags: machine-learning

sns.jointplot(df["Time on Website"], df["Time on App"])
this code is running well and giving the desired graph

sns.lmplot(df["Time on Website"], df["Time on App"])
but this one is showing error

i am getting the error this
Missing required keyword argument `data`.

Answer (score 0):

the function Implot is required pass argument DATA, it's like this:

```
sns.lmplot(data=df, x=""Time on Website", y="Time on App")
```

data is your dataframe, x and y(columns) is the axis of your dataframe